# How much used diskspace will increase when doing Mongo Indexing?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, diskspace

Let say, I have 1GB of data in format: {_id:ObjectId(), expiration:, value:}.  let say around 1000000 records.

If I do an indexing on a non-existing field, e.g. "key", (  db.mytest.ensureIndex({key:1})  ), then in general, how many diskspace will it increase?

of I do indexing on the expiration date, how many will be increased?

Comment: Try it and tell us. Seems like something easy enough to undo.

Answer (score 3):

The size of the index depends upon the number of documents being indexed and the key size.  You should be able to estimate the approximate size of the index on expiration date by multiplying the number of documents by the key size (dates in Mongo are 8 bytes). But as Corey points out, testing is the best way to find out.

If you create an index on a non-existing field, you should not see the index size increase since there is nothing to add to the Btree.